# Telegram android message cell

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout like Telegram message box in android.

When the text is short the message and time are aligned in one single line as follows:
[image: single line msg]

But when the message text is longer the time text view is pushed to the bottom of message like this:
[image: multi line message]

How can i achieve this?

P.s. I tried to read the telegram source but wasn't able to figure it out. And i tried to get the size of my text view in adapter but wasn't successful.

Comment: what you want exactly first image or second image as output ?

Comment: @Nilesh I want to achieve this layout. When my text is short the first image and when my text is long second one. Exactly like Telegram android app

Comment: Have you achieved the desired functionality?

Comment: Nah man... @RawnaldGregoryErickson

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are not aligned in one line... :D I think you can achieve this by wrapping your TextView for time in RelativeLayout like that:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:orientation="horizontal" 
          android:background="@drawable/background" 
          android:padding="10dp" >  

<TextView style="@style/TextView_port" 
          android:id="@+id/text" 
          android:text="Text"  />

<RelativeLayout style="@style/LinearLayout" 
                android:layout_below="@id/text" 
                android:layout_margin="10dp" 
                android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView style="@style/TextView_port" 
              android:text="3:59pm" 
              android:textColor="#73B661"  />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here i found a trick to set your text alignment to justify:

https://dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-how-display

**EDIT**

I finally came up with the solution - the edited code above is for short texts. Check programatically the length of the text and if it is more than 20 for example set orientation of the Linear to vertical and only top margin of the time TextView to -20 - I'll update my answer later if you don't know how :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not going to work if i check the length of the text. Because it kinda checks the length of the textview itself to position them. I mean if there are a lot of characters but all separated by a '\n', the views are positioned like the first picture...

Comment: What about different TextView for any line of the text and the last would be wrapped in LinearLayout with the time TextView... Or you want the text in one TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Your shown example looks like a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) with two [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)s in it (first TextView top-left and second TextView bottom-right).

It should be possible to accomplish this by using a RelativeLayout and two TextViews. The TextViews should be positioned correctly based on the length of the text (the second TextView displaying time should be always in bottom-right corner).